# de Rham's trisection method - English

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, limits-and-convergence

I want to learn more about de Rham's trisection method in

- De Rham, Georges, *Un peu de mathématiques à propos d'une courbe plane*, Elemente der Mathematik 2 (1947): 73-76. http://eudml.org/doc/140463.

Specifically, if there exists a general formula for the limit of a polygon. I have the French version of his article, but I don't have the English version - could anyone provide a link?

Comment: Why do you think there is an English version?

Comment: I just assumed that there would be an English version, please correct me if I'm mistaken somehow

Comment: What might be reasonable to ask is if there is a modern treatment or review of this material that's in English. Google Scholar finds [many citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=17387877627632670746&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) of the original article.

Comment: Protasov's paper says that the limit curve is nowhere smooth, so not given by any analytic formula. But maybe there is some other way to write a formula.

Comment: @Ben what paper is that?

Comment: @DavidRoberts: MR2069197 (2005c:37175) Protasov, V. Yu. (RS-MOSCM)
On the smoothness of de Rham curves. Izv. Ross. Akad. Nauk Ser. Mat. 68 (2004), no. 3, 139–180; translation in Izv. Math. 68 (2004), no. 3, 567–606.

Comment: See https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=489&option_lang=eng
There are the full text in Russian and the references (from which I recommend [17] and [20]) in English.

Answer (score 3):

A popular English-language treatment

*de Boor, Carl*, [**Cutting corners always works**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0167-8396(87)90029-X), Comput. Aided Geom. Des. 4, 125-131 (1987). [ZBL0637.41014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0637.41014).

For this subsequent de Rham paper

MR0095227
de Rham, Georges.
Sur quelques courbes definies par des equations fonctionnelles. (French)
*Univ. e Politec. Torino Rend. Sem. Mat.* **16** (1956/57), 101–113.

there is a translation in

*Edgar, Gerald A. (ed.)*, Classics on fractals, Studies in Nonlinearity. Boulder, CO: Westview Press (ISBN 0-8133-4153-1/pbk). xii, 366 p. (2004). [ZBL1062.28007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1062.28007).